# Which of several assumptions to negate after getting a contradiction out of it?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

For my question I use the natural deduction calculus. There you can deduce from the following three assumptions:

A1. A $\to$ B

A2. $\lnot$ B

A3. A

1. B
2. B $\land$ $\lnot$B

So far, so good. The deductions of 1. and 2. are trivial, so I will not go into detail. Now, according to the natural deduction calculus I could negate *any* of the above assumptions because the contradiction in 2. depends on all three. So I could deduce in 3. that $\lnot$A. But this does not make sense. All we know in 2. is that the *conjunction* of the three assumptions leads to a contradiction and has to be false. But it could be that A is true and just 1. and 2. are false, but here we are I just got $\lnot$A deduced. °.° In my opinion one can only be allowed to deduce: $\lnot$ (A $\to$ B, $\lnot$ B, A).

Comment: Correct: but what does it mean the meta-logic statement: "¬ (A → B, ¬B, A)"? Not all three premises together: thus, we have three cases: (i) $A → B, ¬B \vdash ¬A$, (ii) $A → B, A \vdash B$ and (iii) $A, ¬B \vdash ¬(A → B)$. All three are valid derivations.

Comment: If you deduce a contradiction from a premise A and so you introduce ~A, do you have to somehow cancel A as a premise? Because I am thinking, else you can still use the premise A to deduce all kind of things, in fact quodlibet kind of things since it is false.

Answer (score 1):

> But it could be that A is true and just 1. and 2. are false, but here we are I just got ¬A deduced. °.°

... well, yes.  It *could* be that those two assumptions are actually false, but *at that point* you are still assuming them to be true.

That is: by adding contextual indentation to indicate which assumptions are active, your proof so far has that at line `6.`, assumptions on `1.` and  `2.` are still raised (that is *undischarged*).

$$\begin{array}{|l}\hline\quad\begin{array}{|l}~~1.~A\to\neg B\\\hline\quad\begin{array}{|l}~~2.~B\\\hline\quad\begin{array}{|l}~~3.~A\\\hline~~4.~\neg B\hspace{12ex}{\to}\mathsf E~1,3\\~~5.~B\land \neg B\hspace{9ex}{\land}\mathsf I~2,4\end{array}\\~~6.~\neg A\hspace{17ex}{\neg}\mathsf I~3{-}5\end{array}\\\quad\vdots\end{array}\\\quad\vdots\end{array}$$

Which is basically the derivation for the sequent: $A\to\lnot B, B\vdash\lnot A$

Under the *assumption* that $A\to\lnot B$ and $B$ are true, we deduce that $A$ is false (...because if it were *also* true we would have a contradiction).

---

Now you *could* change the order in which these assumptions are raised and discharged, to prove that: under the assumption that any two are true, there the third will be false.$$\begin{split}A, B&\vdash\lnot(A\to\lnot B)\\A,A\to\lnot B&\vdash\lnot B\\B,A\to\lnot B&\vdash\lnot A\end{split}$$

Comment: So from the three premises A$\to$ B, $\lnot$B, A we can deduce in natural deduction calculus: $\lnot$(A$\to$ B) xor B xor $\lnot$A xor $\lnot$((A$\to$ B) $\land$ $\lnot$B) xor $\lnot$((A$\to$ B) $\land$ A) xor $\lnot$((A$\to$ B) $\land$ $\lnot$B $\land$ A) just like we want, so I could pick any and I‘d be correct, right?